# How do i access the objects inside the array returned by a javascript function

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, arrays, json

This function calls a PHP script which echos a JSON data, it loops through the JSON object, creates a new object and pushes this new object onto an array which is returned by the function

```js
function getTestQuestions() {
        // alert('10');
        var sessionQuestions = [];
        $.getJSON('testservice.php?action=getQuestions', function(json){
            
            
            if (json.your_questions.length > 0) {
                var totalQuestions = json.your_questions.length;
                totalQuestions_global = totalQuestions;



                for (var i = 0; i < totalQuestions; i++) {

                    var question_object = new Object();
                    question_object.serialNo = i;
                    question_object.passage = json.your_questions[i]['passage'];
                    question_object.cur_question = json.your_questions[i]['question'];
                    question_object.option1= json.your_questions[i]['option1'];
                    question_object.option2 = json.your_questions[i]['option2'];
                    question_object.option3 = json.your_questions[i]['option3'];
 

                    sessionQuestions.push(question_object);

                }

            }
        });
        
        return sessionQuestions;
    }
```

The next function calls this function. But i have a problem accessing the objects inside the array. See the code:

```js
function initialTestLoaded() {

                var allQuestions = getTestQuestions();                   

                $('.current_quest').text(allQuestions[0]['serialNo']);
                $('.total_quest').text(testQuestions.length);
```

The code in the last two lines returns an error of being unable to access a "serialNo" ppty of undefined.

This is my first time posting a question here and i trust the good people here will be of great help as always. Thanks

Comment: no no, just pass json response to php, then use json_decode($json, true) it will automatically convert into an array. Then use that array to access elements inside an array. like $array['passage'] etc.

Comment: That happens because `$.getJSON` is an asynchronous function and `getTestQuestions` function will never wait for the result, always returning an undefined value.

Comment: Thanks all. Do i need to json_decode in php first before echoing? Most articles  suggest accessing the json_encoded objects as it is in javascript. My challenge is not that i can't access the json_encoded object in javascript, but that after looping through all the entries and pushing them on to an array in one function, i cant seem to access the elements of this returned array when i call this function in another function. Running Console.log inside the function declaration shows that array is properly populated, but it shows undefined inside the calling function. Please guide me.

Answer (score 0):

In php just use **json_decode**

```
json_decode($jsondata, true);
```

Basic example

```
<?php 
$json_string = 'https://example.com/jsondata.json';
$jsondata = file_get_contents($json_string);
$obj = json_decode($jsondata,true);
echo "<pre>";
print_r($obj);
?>
```